# azure media player click event

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I have to track event when turn on the video(click on big button).
 I show result about "tech-click" but it's not click on the big button.

```
  player = amp(randomId, <any>{
                techOrder: ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "html5FairPlayHLS", "silverlightSS", "html5"],
                "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
                "logo": { "enabled": false },
                controls: true,
                width: attrs.width,
                height: attrs.height,
                autoplay: scope.autoplay,
                poster
            });


  player.addEventListener("tech-click", () => {
        appInsights.trackEvent("homeVideo");                  
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-big-play-button[0]
.addEventListener("click", () => {
                            appInsights.trackEvent("homeVideo");
                        });
```